# Finding Palm Sunday

Tags: perl, datetime

Palm Sunday is the Sunday before Easter Sunday. Finding Easter Sunday can be achieved with:

```
use Time::Moment;
use Time::Moment::Adjusters qw(WesternEasterSunday PreviousDayOfWeek);

# 2018-04-01T00:00:00Z
my $easter_sunday = Time::Moment->new(year => 2018)->with(WesternEasterSunday);
```

Finding the Sunday before that could be achieved with [`Time::Moment::Adjusters`' `PreviousDayOfWeek(7)`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Time-Moment/lib/Time/Moment/Adjusters.pod#PreviousDayOfWeek):

> ```
> $adjuster = PreviousDayOfWeek($day);
> ```
>
> The `$adjuster` adjusts the date to the previous occurrence of the given day of the week [1=Monday, 7=Sunday] that is before the date.

But if I apply this adjuster, I get a Tuesday five days earlier!

```
# 2018-03-27T00:00:00Z
my $palm_sunday = $easter_sunday->with(PreviousDayOfWeek(7))
```

Since Palm Sunday is always seven days prior to Easter Sunday, I could achieve this with [`Time::Moment`'s `minus_days(7)`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Time-Moment/lib/Time/Moment.pod#minus_days), but since I want to find a number of other holidays that are much simpler to find using `Time::Moment::Adjusters`, I would really like to find the root of this unexpected behavior.

Comment: Maybe you found a bug.

Comment: Good job with the [bug report](https://github.com/chansen/p5-time-moment/issues/31). I added a test for it.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the bug and submitted a pull request. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you Simon for the [report](https://github.com/chansen/p5-time-moment/issues/31) and the [PR](https://github.com/chansen/p5-time-moment/pull/32) and thank you @simbabque for the test! I have shipped [v0.44 to CPAN](https://metacpan.org/release/CHANSEN/Time-Moment-0.44). You are excellent citizens in the opensource community!

--
chansen